# Type of induction principle for fixpoint types

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, typed-lambda-calculus, calculus-of-constructions

To the Calculus of Constructions we could add a general fixpoint type constructor (accepting inconsistencies or assuming `F` is a `Functor`):

```
Fix : (* -> *) -> *
in  : ∀F. F (Fix F) -> Fix F
out : ∀F. Fix F -> F (Fix F)
```

We can then write down the type of case discrimination and folding:

```
case : ∀F T. (F (Fix F) -> T) -> Fix F -> T
fold : ∀F T. (F T -> T) -> Fix F -> T
```

But what is the type of induction (if there is one)? I've gotten this far:

```
ind : ∀F T (P : Fix F -> *). (∀(h : Fix F). P h -> P ???) -> (x : Fix F) -> P x
```

Assuming the rest is correct, what should be in the place of `???`?
Alternatively, what is the type of dependent case discrimination?

Comment: The word *induction* is used when we construct an *inductive* type, i.e., the smallest or initial fixed point of a type constructor $F$. However, a general type constructor need not have an initial or smallest fixed point, and therefore no reasonable induction principle can be stated in general.

Comment: If we let $F(X) = X \to \mathsf{Empty}$, what is $\mathsf{Fix}(F)$?

Comment: If we constrain F in some way (for example strictly positive occurrences of X), can we then state a induction principle?

Comment: I think you need an additional constraint over $F$, namely that it is behaves well over "fibrations", i.e. that there is some function `lift_fiber : forall A : *, (A -> *) -> (F A -> *)`. This is certainly enough to express what you need.

Comment: Okay interesting, but then could you write down the type of `induction` for all `Fix F`? Or you could write down `induction` for a specific `F` in `Fix F` only?

Comment: @cody: right, and we don't need any strict positivity, just covariance, in order to *phraase* the induction principle.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, the paper [Generic derivation of induction for impredicative encodings in Cedille](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322191243_Generic_derivation_of_induction_for_impredicative_encodings_in_Cedille) shows a type for induction on a fixpoint type. It can look like:

```
ind : ∀F T (P : Fix F -> *). ((h : F (Σ (Fix F) P)) -> P (in (map fst h))) -> (x : Fix F) -> P x
```

With `Σ` being the dependent product and `map` the functor map of `F`.

Comment: Just a note, having this `Fix` type is not enough to derive induction for inductive datatypes like `Nat` or `List`. You'd also need an induction principle for `F`. If `F` is constructed from unit, sums and products then you'd need induction principles for those.